# Excess tags in CKEditor right after first initialization

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Did anybody face to such issue?
I have CKEditor completely installed and worked BUT whatever i type in there (for example Hello world) i always get tons of ugly formatted HTML such as:

```
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 99999999; display: none; top: 0pt; right: 0pt; bottom: auto; left: auto; height: auto; width: auto; padding: 5px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.2; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0.9;">
    <p style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; display: none;">
    </p>
</div>
```

In initially TextArea for its replacement is empty so it is not the reason this HTML comes from CKEditor only.

My configuration of CKEditor in this case:

```
CKEDITOR.replace(optionList.editorName, {
     "toolbar": optionList.editorType || "Full",
     "uiColor": optionList.editorColor || "#EEE",
     "height": "200px",
     "minHeight": "200px",
     "maxHeight": "200px",
     "startupShowBorders": false,
     "toolbarCanCollapse": false,
     "fillEmptyBlocks": false,
     "ignoreEmptyParagraph": true,
     "resize_enabled": false,
     "filebrowserBrowseUrl": "/App_Vendors/FSManager/"
});
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: I've never seen that kind of problem. Do you have a url to test?

Comment: Is this even a problem? http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21857

Comment: Yes, it is mine :) Was solved by uninstalling Translator plugin in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed - answer is here - http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21857

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.